# How to calculate if set of values are uniformly distributed?

Tags: statistics

I have a set of the following values

0.275709,
0.911413,
0.534146,
0.350485,
0.834308,
0.637119,
0.000000,

I need to figure out if these values are uniformly distributed using an alpha value of 0.0001

How can I do this?